# WPengine and git

Tags: wordpress, git

For some weird reason when I push to wpengine, my files get updated without a problem -- but it will not delete files only within my the theme folder.

Here is a list of what's going on:

1. I have no trouble deleting the theme file, the theme will be removed. However if the theme is added back, the removed files within the folder are still present
2. When I pull the git repo the files are correct
3. Any file removed within the theme's directory is not updated
4. I reverted the environment back to the production (by overwriting the env with production's db and files), when I pushed my code everything was correct.

I have NO idea how to fix this. Please help!

Comment: This sounds like confusion about how Git versions files.  It might help to spell out exact steps/commands you are using and why the result you are getting is unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

[`suwebdev/wpengine`](https://github.com/suwebdev/wpengine) mentions:

> Custom components of this site are created as themes and plugins.
>   These are stored in separate repositories and brought into the production code **using Git submodules**.

Double check if you see a `.gitmodules` in your main repo, which refers to your themes folder you are trying to update.
That would explain why a local change (within the theme folder, which is actually its own Git repository, as a submodule) is *not* reflected to your deployment process.